# Java (Selenium) - получение ссылки из исходного кода

Tags: java, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

В Firefox с помощью инструмента "Исследовать элемент" в интересующем куске кода есть ссылки, которые хочу брать используя методы библиотеки Selenium. Вот этот кусок исходного кода, который вижу в Firefox

```
<table class="gray-table">
                <tbody><tr class="">
                    <th style="width: 230px;">Производитель</th>
                    <th>Наименование</th>

                    <th style="width: 140px; text-align: center;">Цена</th>
                </tr>

                    <tr class="">
                        <td>KRAFTTECH</td>

                        <td><a href="ССЫЛКА, КОТОРУЮ НУЖНО ВЗЯТЬ" target="_blank">Комплект сцепления</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><noindex><a target="_blank" href="/Web/price/art/W01210H9/manufacturer6107/KRAFTTECH" rel="nofollow">Найти</a></noindex></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <td>VALEO</td>

                        <td><a href="ССЫЛКА, КОТОРУЮ НУЖНО ВЗЯТЬ" target="_blank">Диск</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><noindex><a target="_blank" href="/Web/price/art/VW09/manufacturer21/VALEO" rel="nofollow">Найти</a></noindex></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

Те ссылки, которые хочу взять тут обозначил как "ССЫЛКА, КОТОРУЮ НУЖНО ВЗЯТЬ". Пробовал использовать различные методы поиска по имени тэга, пытался искать используя имя класса и т. д. Перепробовал разные варианты, пока не удалось получить желаемый результат. Буду благодарен помощи!

Comment: xPath не пробовал значит

Comment: пробуй по `By.cssSelector("table > tbody > tr > td > a ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно пробежаться в таблице по всем `tr`(c помощью FindElement**s**) найти в каждом второй `td` и взять тег `a`
Дальше у вас будет лист элементов, через который вы получите как `.Text` так и саму ссылку `.GetAttribute("href")`
Не знаю как в Java List называется, напишу на шарпе, уверен разберетесь:

```
List<IWebElement> linkElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tr td:nth-child(2) a")).ToList();

foreach(IWebElement link in linkElements)
{
    string href = link.GetAttribute("href");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Вот немного не понятно, что обозначает "tr td:nth-child(2) a" ?

Comment: @Денис второй `td`, нужные вам ссылки содержатся во втором `td`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Получается! :)

Answer (score 0):

наш элемент находится в `table > tbody > tr > td > a`. Значит нужно искать там

```
    // находим все элементы 
    List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("table > tbody > tr > td > a ")); 

    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("href")); // печатаем значение 
    }
```

Comment: вы левые ссылки тоже получили, сеньор) и тут `table > tbody > tr > td > a` нет тега `a` в реале, там буду следующие значения: KRAFTTECH, VALEO

Comment: очень странно. печатает мне именно значение атрибута. и вообще есть тег "а"